# Why can't I upload shapefiles into my SpatiaLite database

Tags: qgis, spatialite

When I try to import a layer into my SpatiaLite Database, I get this error message.
[image]

Why is this happening now ?

Comment: Impossible to say with this information. For some reason your QGIS cannot write into your database/disk/database file.

Comment: Please remember to include error messages as text in the body of the question.

Comment: `Why is this happening now` Was it working previously?